# Does "fukushuu suru" mean "review" or "revise"?

Tags: meaning

Does *fukushuu suru* mean "to review" or "to revise"? Which meaning may be closer to actual usage?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Japanese.SE! We like to have only one question per, er, question. Please ask the other question (about _machiawase_, _kaigi_, _shūgō_) separately.

Comment: Are you revising vocabulary for an exam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[from goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/89503/meaning/m0u/%E5%BE%A9%E7%BF%92/)

> １ 教えられたことを繰り返し練習すること。復習。さらえ。「書き取りのお―」

It means [review](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/review).

> to go over (lessons, studies, work, etc.) in review.

It also means revise, if you are going by the [British English definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/revise?s=t).

> British. to review (previously studied materials) in preparation for an examination.

---

[from goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/191698/meaning/m0u/%E5%BE%A9%E8%AE%90/)

It can also mean "(exact) revenge", but it uses different kanji.

> ［名］(スル)かたきうちをする。仕返しをする。報復。「―する機会を待つ」

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to Amani's post, it looks like this *fukushū* reading has four possible spellings and three meanings -- three spellings with verb senses, and one proper noun:

- [復習](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BE%A9%E7%BF%92): to review, to go back over something, to study it again
- [復讐](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BE%A9%E8%AE%90)・[復讎](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BE%A9%E8%AE%8E) (second spelling less common): to exact revenge, to wreak vengeance upon someone, to avenge a wrong
- [福州](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%A6%8F%E5%B7%9E): [Fuzhou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzhou), the capital of Fujian province in China